# Almost every request to a single file (mod-rewrite)?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Here's my current rule:

```
RewriteRule (.*) view.php?id=$1
```

However, I still need certain files to differ. When the site is visited to root (so that `(.*)` is basically empty), index.php should be shown, as usual. Then there are a few PHP-files that need to be accessible by their default filename.

Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT:**
Here's my code based on Crunch's advice:

```
RewriteRule (.*)\.(css|js) - [L]
RewriteRule / - [L]
RewriteRule foo.php - [L]
RewriteRule (.*) view.php?id=$1 [L]
```

It seems that everything else works, except the root. As you can see, I removed the `/` from the filenames, as they didn't work before. I don't know any solution for the root, as I can't take the `/` off it :D

**EDIT 2:**
Fixed it with this kind of dirty, but working hack:

```
RewriteRule ^\s*$ - [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteRule / - [L]
RewriteRule /realPhpFile.php - [L]
```

The dash `-` means, that "nothing happens".

Comment: Please take a look at my updated question. And thanks for your reply :)